# Reading Data in Chunks Using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, chunking

I have a block of code that looks like this,

```
entities = self.session.query(Entities).filter(Entities.parent_id == 0)
    
index_data = {}
for entity in entities:
    data = entity.__dict__
    data['addresses'] = [address.__dict__ for address in entity.addresses]
    data['relationships'] = [relationship.__dict__ for relationship in entity.relationships_parent]
    index_data[data['id']] = data
```

I am trying to read the data, process it a little bit as shown above and store in the NoSQL database (I have only given the reading part here).

I noticed that this loop takes a really long time to complete. I suspect it is due to the amount of data I read with the first line of code? Maybe in terms of network delays? Because the memory utilization here is fine.

I need a solution using SQLAlchemy code.

I am thinking that maybe this could be solved by reading the data in chunks? How can I do this? If the problem is something else, how can I solve it?

Comment: `entity.relationships_parent` probably sends another query for every entity. Try using other load strategy https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html?highlight=relationship#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.lazy

Comment: The thing is, I tried running this on a small dataset and it was pretty fast. However, when I run it on a larger dataset, it became really slow. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: This really helped. Maybe you can add this as an answer. The 'selectin' strategy gave me a real boost in speed.